# numpy multiple if in case statements

Tags: python, numpy

Hi all I am trying to add a column in my DF based on the value of another column.

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(If df.col in [3, 4, 5] then 1 
                         elif df.col in [1, 2] then 2 
                         elif df.col in [6, 7] then 3)
```

what would be the correct syntax with 2 or more "if is in" statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.select` which is for multiple statements (default is 0 but you can set it with `default` arguement):

```
df['new_col'] = np.select([df.col.isin([3,4,5]), df.col.isin([1,2]), df.col.isin([6,7])],[1,2,3])
```

sample output:

```
  col   new_col
0   7   3
1   0   0
2   7   3
3   4   1
4   1   2
5   6   3
6   9   0
7   3   1
8   5   1
9   9   0
```